# Send CSRF token to React SPA from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, single-page-application, csrf, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a `Rails API` and I use `devise` for authentication. My client side is a React SPA.

I tried turning on the `protect_from_forgery` in my `application_controller` as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:otp_attempt])
  end

end
```

But with every `put/post` request it throws an error:

`Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

This makes sense because I am not sending back any `CSRF token` with my requests.
It seems like the way to do this for rails is to add `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in my `application.html.erb` but I am using `jbuilder` to convert everything to `json` before sending it to my SPA.

Is there a way I can access this information in the client side so I can turn on the protection for CSRF?

Comment: Is your React standalone app or rendering via Rails ?

Comment: @7urkm3n my react is a standalone app with a node server and it makes API requests to my Rails app

Comment: then just ignore it better with `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: @7urkm3n wouldn't that mean that my app would susceptible to CSRF attacks?

Comment: take a look to this gem: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Comment: @7urkm3n hmm I am not sure anymore if I am trying to fix something that doesn't exist. I already added `rack-cors` to my application and restricted the `origin` to my app. Does this mean that I don't need to use `protect_from_forgery` at all and rack cors takes care of it?

Comment: As per the best practice, you should have more protection than just checking Origin. Under some circumstances it might be possible for an attacker to remove or even fake an origin header, albeit that's not very likely. Look at other CSRF protections like for example double posting, which provides reasonable security while being stateless. You have to implement the check in Rails though, but that's really easy.